# Nested IF returns the final value without validating the other conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a 3 condition "IF" function on my excel spreadsheet to return me some missing information. The formula is as follows:ff

```
=IF(C2="";"No_Email";IF(D2="";"No_Title";IF(E2="";"No_Phone";"OK")))
```

My question here is:

- After the first "true" condition, it returns that validation and exits the formula. Is it possible to run all of them 3 validations and return all the missing information or it is an excel limitation to that?

Hope you guys can help me :)
Have a great day.

Comment: Of course it does. The 3rd parameter is the _else_ result, so it only gets returned if the condition is false. If it's true, you get the _if_ result, and evaluation stops. I'm pretty sure the little popup after you type the opening bracket explains this. Also, I had no idea that semicolons were allowed in this context or had any meaning in Excel really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
="Missing: "& IF((IF(C2="";"Email ";"") & IF(D2="";"Title ";"") & IF(E2="";"Phone";""))="";"nothing";) & ((IF(C2="";"Email ";"") & IF(D2="";"Title ";"") & IF(E2="";"No_Phone";"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tom but when I use your formula, on the the missing values I get "Missing: FALSE" instead of the the value of the missing information.

Comment: Okay, edited it. Didn't test it beforehand. Should work now.